# Examples of other Hermitian Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In my study of quantum mechanics, I have found that from a purely mathematical perspective, it would seem as though hermitian operators are an excellent way to generate orthogonal functions.  However, I was attempting to find arbitrary hermitian operators to serve this purpose, and I quickly realized that you can use any arbitrary number of P operators as derivatives, and X operators as x variables (this is all in the position basis).  Based on this, I began to wonder if you only need X and P operators to construct all Hermitian operators.  My instincts tell me this seems wrong.  Are there any examples of Hermitian operators that can't be formed with just X and P operators?  And of course I am looking for operators that act in Hilbert space, not simply some nxn matrix.

Comment: You should probably specify that you're looking for Hermitian operators acting on the Hilbert space of $L^2$ integrable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ so that you don't get answers like "yeah just consider this $2\times 2$ matrix."

Comment: Do you mean polynomials in $X,P$ or do you allow arbitrary functions $V(X)$?

Comment: @KeithMcClary: Yes I mean something that cannot be formed with simply polynomials of X and P.  I exclude V(X) under the assumption that it can be taylor expanded.

Comment: But there are $V(X)$ that don't have convergent series. Still, I think your question might have some mathematical meaning.